# Sql query for date compare

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to compare dates and then select the quantity
my function is like this

```
public function get_quantity($product_id,$event_start_date) {
  $qStr ="SELECT 
              order_items.quantity
             FROM
              order_items
             WHERE
              product_id = $product_id 
             AND
              (SELECT shows.event_end_date FROM
               shows
               INNER JOIN order_items ON
               shows.order_id = order_items.order_id
               WHERE
               order_items.product_id = $product_id 
               LIMIT 1) > $event_start_date";
    $query = $this->db->query($qStr);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

i have to compare it with all dates greater then event start date which i am providing in the function argument

Comment: Is this PHP? If so please add the tag to the question.

Comment: Just a quick look: `$event_start_date` should be surrounded by single quotes in your query. This is a Q&A site and your post lacks a Q.